# Get an image from gallery and preview it in another activity in android studio

Tags: android

I want to select an image in the gallery by pressing a button and preview that selected image in another activity.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public  static final  int REQUEST_CODE=1234;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("picture",REQUEST_CODE);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}


public  void send(View view){

    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"picture"),REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

From this code button access to gallery and pass it to Main2Activity .

**Main2Activity**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView iv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("picture");
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
}
```

In this code we can open gallery and select an image.After select the image it open the second activity but does not preview the image.How to preview image?

Comment: compare: `intent.putExtra("picture",REQUEST_CODE);` and `Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("picture");` - do you expect miracles?

Comment: @pskink when he said it would be bitmap!!

Comment: @AkashDubey what do you mean?

Comment: I prefer you should pass the URI instead of the Bitmap itself and use Glide on the other end. And URI implements Parcelable So it won't be a problem.

Comment: @pskink is it "picture" or "data" for the bitmap??

Comment: I'm new to android.Can you please tell me how to do that code. Thanks

Comment: use `data.getData` / `intent.setData` in the first activity and  `intent.getData` / `iv.setImageURI` in the second activity - thats all

Comment: @SanjeewaMilan Check My edited answer. It may hep you.

Comment: @SabyasachiM it not working yet

Comment: @SanjeewaMilan Try with my edited code. It is working for me.

Comment: @SabyasachiM Thanks for helping.. It's working..

Comment: @pskink thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData( );

                Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                i.setData(selectedImageUri);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
```

**Main2Activity**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ImageView imageView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

            imageView = findViewById(R.id.img);

            if(getIntent()!= null){
            Uri imageUri=getIntent().getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: here is why: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html - it will not work in most cases

Comment: i already did - see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593158/get-an-image-from-gallery-and-preview-it-in-another-activity-in-android-studio#comment94049329_53593158) above

Comment: @pskink Check my edited answer. Thanks for the info.

Comment: why so complex?  btw it will not work as you are using `Intent#putExtra(String name, Parcelable value)` when sending and `Bundle#getString(String name)` when receiving

Comment: @pskink Oh I forgot to convert that uri  to String.

Comment: no, just pass `Uri` directly in `Intent` - why dont you want to use `Intent#setData`??

Comment: isnt it better now? much more simpler that your original approach

Comment: Yes boss...Thanks for simple approach.